# What is the signature of the brand callback urls?

Tags: docusignapi

I can't find any documentation on what the signature of the brand callback urls (for a PowerForm) are. For example, is it just a GET request to the url, or is it maybe a POST with information included in the body as well?

**Update**:

From testing using their sandbox environment, the callbacks aren't callbacks, they are redirects, so GETs with query params. The query params are:

```
{
  env: <Envelope ID>,
  pf: <PowerForm ID>,
  r: <someUUID>,
}
```

`env` seems to be the Envelope ID from the PowerForm, and `pf` matched the id of the PowerForm, so that's some progress. Not sure what `r` is, though I imagine it's the UUID of the completed form (revision maybe). Still would love to see some documentation actually explaining the signature in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some additional research through the app and sandbox, and looking at the data my server has been getting, this is the base signature (assuming you haven't added additional query params when you define the url:

```
GET <specifiedBrandUrl>?env=<uuid>&pf=<uuid>&r=<uuid>
```

Where:

- `env` is the Envelope ID of the PowerForm
- `pf` is the PowerForm ID
- `r` is the Recipient ID

I was able to determine `env` by looking at the "Form Data" option in the template. I was able to determine `pf` since that matches the `PowerFormId` query param in the link to the PowerForm. I was able to determine `r` by downloading the CSV of the PowerForm and noticed that the id I was getting matched the `RecipientId` in the CSV.

@DocuSign. Please add the above to your docs. It took me days to figure that out. It should have taken 30 seconds.